# PHP Regular Expression to match define() function

Tags: php, regex, string, file-io

I'm doing a translation of php script and want to gain some time by doing some automatization
The file contains very large number of lines like these

```
define('LNG_NewsletterNameIsNotValid', 'Email Campaign name is not Valid');
define('LNG_UnableToCreateNewsletter', 'Unable to create an Campaña de Email');
define('LNG_HLP_NewsletterName', 'You must insert \\\'Custom Fields\\\' in the field.');
define('LNG_UnableToUpdateNewsletter', 'Unable to update '. LNG_xxx . ' from Email Campaign');
```

and I would like to:

- open each php file
- go through each line
- get the string corresponding to each define()
- put a field where I should write the translation
- save the new string to the file

**I have the script almost done**, except for the part for getting the string to be translated from each line. I point several examples so you can see that translation strings can contain references to other variables, quotes, etc.

Do I need a regular expression, right?
Can anyone help me with one?

Comment: Just so clear(er) "define('stringX', 'stringY');" should become "define(tokenX, tokenY);"...right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd probably be better of using [`token_get_all`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php). While regex could probably get most of them, It doesn't have the necessary complexity to parse PHP correctly ([just like regexes can't parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)). `token_get_all` would only miss edge cases, such as using a variable-function or `eval`'ing text.

If your doing language translations it might be worth looking into [`gettext`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) instead of using `define`.

Comment: Kendall, that was awesome. I can't change define for gettext because I'm not the developer of the script, but I'll send that suggestion to them. Thanks!